# system() occasionally returns 2

Tags: c, shell, system

I have coded a function using `system()` library function as below:

```
int execute(const char* cmd)
{
  int ret = system(cmd);

  if (ret != -1)
  {
    if (WIFEXITED(ret))
      ret = WEXITSTATUS(ret);
    else
      ret = -1;
  }

  LINFO( "execute %s, ret = %d", cmd, ret);  // logging
  return ret;
}
```

Then, I called it with a shell script as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
cd $(dirname $0)

agent_name=`grep 'agent_name' ../etc/config.ini |awk '{ print $3 }'`
py='../../python26/bin/python'

check_alive()
{
    status=`ps -ef | grep "$agent_name" | grep -v "grep" |wc -l`

    if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
        # process exist
        echo "$agent_name already exist"
        exit 1
    fi    

}

check_alive
eval '$py ../bin/agent.py -d'

status=`ps -ef | grep "$agent_name" | grep -v "grep" |wc -l`
if  [ $status -lt 1 ] 
then
    echo "run failed"
    exit -1
else
    echo "run succ"
    exit 0
fi
```

But sometimes there was a odd return code of 2, as below:

```
[INFO]execute ./admin/trystart.sh, ret = 1
[INFO]execute ./admin/trystart.sh, ret = 1
[INFO]execute ./admin/trystart.sh, ret = 2
[INFO]execute ./admin/trystart.sh, ret = 2
[INFO]execute ./admin/trystart.sh, ret = 1
[INFO]execute ./admin/trystart.sh, ret = 1
[INFO]execute ./admin/trystart.sh, ret = 1
[INFO]execute ./admin/trystart.sh, ret = 1
[INFO]execute ./admin/trystart.sh, ret = 1
[INFO]execute ./admin/trystart.sh, ret = 2
```

I would like to understand why there was a return code of 2.

================new 2015/06/12 13:54============================

I have found that when the system() returns 2, there was a error message of bash as below:

```
bash: xmalloc: locale.c:73: cannot allocate 2 bytes (0 bytes allocated)
```

Comment: This is a very well formatted question. No improvement needed. Just as a side note, the reason may be behind `return ret`, where `ret = system(cmd)`. `system(cmd)` might equsl `2`.

Comment: @JamesSmith If `system` returned `2` then he would hit the `!= -1` case and `WIFEXITED` should return false and `ret` should be set to `-1` I believe.

Comment: As an aside. Look into `pgrep` instead of your pipeline and that `eval` is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @EtanReisner Sorry, I must have overlooked that. But, will `WEXITEDSTATUS(ret)` return 2?

Comment: @JamesSmith Yes, when the process exits with a return code of `2` which I don't see in that script and is presumably the question being asked here.

Comment: Can you post everything in your C file?  Maybe I'm just dumb, but I've never seen `LINFO` before.  also, posting `../bin/agent.py` would be really helpful, too.

Comment: @EtanReisner If eval is failed, then this script will exit prematurely and return 2?

Comment: @johnny_boy LINFO is a logging function into local file writed by myself, you can just see it as printf.

Comment: @Hetiu And if `eval` does fail and return code `2`? Why would that cause the main script to exit with that status?

Comment: @EtanReisner  '../bin/agent.py -d' never return 2 in my control, and there will always return 1 in ideal condition. But I don't know why it return 2.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @RossRidge CentOS release 6.5 (Final)  2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The status code of 2 is being returned by your shell. Without a lot more details, it will be difficult to diagnose. Adding the actual error message produced by the shell was useful.

If you shell is `bash` -- as it now appears to be -- then the status return code of 2 indicates a memory allocation error, which is confirmed by the error message generated by `bash`:

```
bash: xmalloc: locale.c:73: cannot allocate 2 bytes (0 bytes allocated)
```

Line 73 is, as far as I can see, the first memory allocation performed by a newly-started `bash` process (which is confirmed by the error message's indication that no bytes have yet been allocated), so it seems likely that the problem is that malloc cannot allocate any memory.

It is possible that there really is no memory available, particularly if you are running on a heavily-congested system with no swap configured. But there are a few hints scattered around the internet which suggest that this might have to do with memory protection options; in particular, configurations in which `sbrk` is not available but the `malloc` library expects to be able to use it.

You might want to start further diagnosis by verifying whether it is possible to reliably start new shells:

```
for i in {0..999}; do sh -c 'exit 0' || echo Failure $?; done
```

---

*An earlier guess, which might be of use to someone else. The fix to the invocation of `exit` is recommended, even though it probably had nothing to do with the particular problem in this question.*

The `dash` shell, used as a `/bin/sh` implementation by a number of distributions, returns status code 2 when the shell exits as a result of an error condition.

One possible culprit from the above script is

```
 exit -1
```

Status return codes are eight-bit unsigned values; in other words, legal return codes range from 0 to 255. -1 is not in that range, and you shouldn't use it in a call to `exit`.

Bash's `exit` builtin (like the C `exit` function) simply uses the low order byte of the supplied return code, so with bash you would have seen a return code of 255. But the dash builtin `exit` expects its argument to be an unsigned number, and complains that -1 is not a valid number.

Since `exit` is a special builtin and the shell is not interactive, the error causes the shell to exit, as per [the Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01). Dash sets the exit code to 2 when it exits because of a shell error.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking that the 255 got truncated before it got logged. That makes more sense.

Comment: But even when I reset the content of the script ./admin/trystart.sh only  'exit 1', the problem happens again.

Comment: I have found that when the system() returns 2, there was a error message of bash as: "bash: xmalloc: locale.c:73: cannot allocate 2 bytes (0 bytes allocated)"

Comment: @Hetiu: Interesting. OK, my guess was wrong then. I edited the answer, but I don't have anything really solid to add. What bash version are you using? Did you update your bash from a centos repository, or in some other way?

Comment: @rici Finally, this issue occured when I build the caller c codes with gcc -m32 and run in 64-bit system. As described in this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=870914

Comment: @hetiu: OK, that makes sense. The fact that you are doing a 32-bit compile in a 64-bit environment is, at least, interesting enough to mention, but it's not something I would have guessed off the top of my head.